# How do I search and replace the contents of multiple Wordpress posts all at once?

Tags: wordpress, replace, find, lines

Ok I have over 500 posts on my website (*using wordpress*). I trying to replace the < !--More--> tag in multiple posts to single line by itself.
Example

**This:**

```
Start of post.......

< !---more--> ...post continues...
```

**To:**

```
Start of post.........

< !---more-->

...post continues...
```

It would be great if there is no spacing between lines. Thanks in advance..

Comment: How comfortable are you with running/writing queries to run against your MySQL database?

Comment: Not too comfy, but I can give it a try.

Comment: There are plugins out there, but they only seem to work on a single line basis.

Answer (score 2):

[Search RegEx](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-regex/) is a good plugin to be able to search and replace with Grep through all posts and pages.